# Could anyone explain the Hidden Sequence problem in CodeChef?

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I'm trying to solve the [Hidden Sequence](https://www.codechef.com/problems/HDDN) problem on Code Chef, but I don't fully understand the explanation. I especially don't understand what's the use of *Y* in the triplets.

> We know that there is a hidden sequence *A<sub>1</sub>,A<sub>2</sub>,…,A<sub>N</sub>* which contains only integers between 1 and *K* inclusive. We have acquired *M* triplets (*X<sub>1</sub>,Y<sub>1</sub>,Z<sub>1</sub>*),(*X<sub>2</sub>,Y<sub>2</sub>,Z<sub>2</sub>*),…,(*X<sub>M</sub>,Y<sub>M</sub>,Z<sub>M</sub>*). A very reliable source has given us intel that for each valid *i*, the *Y<sub>i</sub>*-th occurrence of the integer *X<sub>i</sub>* in the sequence *A* is *A<sub>Z<sub>i</sub></sub>*, i.e. *A<sub>Z<sub>i</sub></sub>=X<sub>i</sub>* and there are *Y*<sub>*i*</sub>−1 indices *j*<*Z<sub>i</sub>* such that *A<sub>j</sub>=X<sub>i</sub>*
>
> Find any sequence *A* consistent with this information or determine that no such sequence exists.

Could anyone explain it?

Answer (score 0):

The hidden array may have duplicate values, like [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1].

One of the triplets could be *X*=3, *Y*=2, *Z*=6.

This tells us that the *second* 3 is at position 6. So:

- *X* = the value
- *Y* = the occurrence of that value *X* (whether it is the first, second, third, ... occurrence)
- *Z* = the position of the *Y*-th occurrence of that value *X*

This may be the only info you will get about the value 3. So you might not get a triplet saying *X*=3, *Y*=1, *Z*=3, which would tell you where the *first* 3 is positioned. Instead your algorithm must *derive* that from the other triplets.

The algorithm should somehow stay aware that in the first 5 positions there *must* be a 3. From other triplets it will know similar things. At a certain point this bulk of information will not allow that 3 to occur at just *any* of those 5 positions, as some positions will be needed for other values. This will narrow down the possibilities, until maybe only a few are left over, or maybe none.

Hope this explains what *Y* is about.

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?